# How to solve Java Native Interface Error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I am getting this error while running "flutter doctor --android licence" command what should I do now.

Why i am getting this error?Should i uninstall JDK and download another version? If then which version should I download.

Comment: What error?  You have not provided enough detail for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.